# How to use javascript variable in jsf components?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

index.xhtml

```
<h:graphicImage title="#{bean.m_strRecentlyUsedImg eq 'Y' ? OMNIGEN.RECENTLY_USED : OMNIGEN.RECENTLY_USED_HIDE}" id="recentlyUsedImg" alt="#{bean.m_strRecentlyUsedImg eq 'Y' ? OMNIGEN.RECENTLY_USED : OMNIGEN.RECENTLY_USED_HIDE}" name="group.png onclick="showRecentlyUsed()" />
```

javascript

```
var m_strRecentlyUsedImg = 'Y';
showRecentlyUsed(){
  m_strRecentlyUsedImg = 'N';
```

}

this is the 
bean.java where getter setter are written.

```
public String getM_strRecentlyUsedImg() {
    return m_strRecentlyUsedImg;
}

/**
 * @param m_strRecentlyUsedImg the m_strRecentlyUsedImg to set
 */
public void setM_strRecentlyUsedImg(String m_strRecentlyUsedImg) {
    this.m_strRecentlyUsedImg = m_strRecentlyUsedImg;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you just can't. What is the actual usecase for which you think you need this as a solution?

Comment: any other way you can do this?

Comment: Uhhhh... sure... use a javascript onclick event handler that change the title... If you need different texts and want to define those on the tags, use passThrough attributes and read those in the javascript event handler

Comment: Firstly, I have done using setAttribute..but it dint work

Comment: I nowhere mentioned anything like 'setAttribute' hence I have no clue what you are talking about

Comment: I have to display title on the basis of flag.

Comment: Yes, but then either have the flag server side or do as I stated when you just want to defile the 'labels on the tag... using passthrough attributes and read those from the dom in your evenrt handler